# Keep getting 'reload' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Tags: path, environment-variables, windows-10

I replaced 'Path' in environment variables/user variables/variable value after following a tutorial on installing MongoDB. Now I can't get my apps to run locally using npm reload. When I type 'reload .' on the command prompt, I get 'reload' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' I don't know what I had as my default variable value for path before I messed with it and it's too late to recover my PC's old state. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The default path in a fresh Windows 10 x64 install is the following:
`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Additionally it seems like you want to add a reload executable to your path so that it will run from any working directory in the command prompt. You would add the path to npm reload as such:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; path_to_reload_executable\;`

which will be wherever you installed Node and NPM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get 'npm reload' running again by replacing PATH in user variables with the following:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm